# Discussion: Either consolidate tags or allow more than 5

Tags: feature-request

Suggestion: Either consolidate tags or allow more than 5

We currently have multiple tags with overlapping meanings. For example the tags: "svd", "matrix-factorization" and "linear algebra". I think that there is an eigenvalue related one as well.

With so many synonyms, it is logical to include all of them so users who are only looking for one of do not miss out on my question. This leaves less "tag allowance" to add tags that describe what I am applying linear algebra to.

So my suggestion is to either allow more than five tags to be used or to consolidate the tags. For example, all of the examples mentioned above could be catergorised as "linear-algebra".

Comment: I beg to differ with some of your assumptions, at least in the cases of the tags you point out, because they are distinct. They are in a hierarchy, with SVD being a form of matrix factorization, which is part of linear algebra. In this case there does not appear to be any problem: [tag:svd] will work fine. Similarly, eigenvalues are a linear algebra concept but only peripherally related to SVD or matrix factorization.  Consolidation would remove those distinctions, reducing the information provided by existing tags. This looks like a good reason to disfavor consolidation.

Comment: I've seen no evidence that a limit of 5 bites many users hard. It obliges the poster (and just as important anybody else adding or subtracting tags) to identify which tags are most appropriate. Adding more tags would just be likely to increase false positive or marginal hits in searches.

Comment: Please, consider: i) removing the word "suggestion" from title (add it to the question body) and; ii) add the tag "discussion" (just suggestions). I am upvoting your question because you raised an important point which is to keep the tags organized in the site (for example, by using proper synonyms). However, I think you did not provide good examples of synonyms, as pointed by whuber. I also agree with Nick that if there was not a tag limit, searching questions by label would be less effective. Welcome to CV Meta!!!